# Any middlewares to run Docker containers successively?

Tags: docker

For example, when I have Docker containers A, B and C which have different runtime each other, I want to run them successively.

```
A -> (wait A done) -> B -> (wait B done) -> C
```

Is there any middlewares to realize this? or can I do this with `docker-compose` or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing things "the Docker way" everything should be treated as it's own independent microservice as such docker/docker compose don't have anything built in to do this. Compose will always start dependencies in order but it won't wait for them to finish starting so it can't do things like say waiting for your database server to fire up before starting the web server.

There's a wealth of information on this topic available here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

I've provided a brief summary below:

**If the dependency container is a network service**

[wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) allows you to wait for a port to be accessible before running a command (example from https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

**If it's not a network service or "finished" condition is more complex than port just being accessbile**

Alternatively you'll need to implement a wrapper script that confirms a service is available before starting the current containers service (taken from https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```